# What animals can a Shaman choose from for their Spirit Animal?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, shaman

I'm curious about Pathfinder's shaman class, but I'm unsure about what animals I'm allowed to have as a spirit animal. The book says that the spirit animal aspect uses the Arcane Bond rules, but does that mean I'm limited to only what's in the list of familiars? Or is it the same list as the animal companions for, say, a druid or ranger? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Since it uses the [Arcane Bond](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard#TOC-Arcane-Bond-Ex-or-Sp-) rules, that would mean you are limited to the choices for [Familiars](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar). If you were allowed to use Animal Companions, there would be wording more like [Rangers' Hunter's Bond](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger#TOC-Hunter-s-Bond-Ex-) or the [Hunter's Animal Companion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/hunter#TOC-Animal-Companion-Ex-):

> This ability functions like the druid animal companion ability (which is part of the Nature Bond class feature)

Comment: Yeah, remember that the class is a mix of witch and druid classes, so the spirit animal is not a combat pet, but a familiar.

Comment: @ShadowKras it's a mix of  *oracle* and witch (Druid and witch would give some basis for combat pet, because Druid).

Comment: My bad, i meant oracle. The druid is simply for the spell list. You could say it's a mix of the three classes, really.